# Singleton class can't find ctor but compiles, runs, and leaves instance uninitialized

Tags: c++, visual-c++, singleton

I am having trouble with my implementation of the singleton pattern in MSVC++ 17 version 15.5.5. I am compiling with the flag `/std:c++17`.

My implementation consists of the following helper class:

```
#pragma once
#include <cassert>

template<class T>
class Singleton : private T
{
public:
    virtual ~Singleton() = default;

    template<typename ... Targs>
    static T & initInstance(Targs && ... args)
    {
        assert(instance == nullptr);
        instance = new Singleton<T>(std::forward<Targs>(args)...); //The constructor of T might be inaccessible here so let our own ctor call it
        return *instance;
    }

    static T & getInstance()
    {
        assert(instance != nullptr);
        return *instance;
    }

private:
    template<typename ... Targs>
    explicit Singleton(Targs && ... args)
        : T{ std::forward<Targs>(args)... }
    {}

    static T * instance;
};

template<class T>
T * Singleton<T>::instance = nullptr;
```

One aim of this implementation is to have some form of lazy initialization but without the redundant `if` statement that gets executed every time `getInstance()` is called. Only the very first time would be useful because the instance would need to be initialized but after that the `if` is just overhead. To do this, I created the function `initInstance()` that you will have to call before being able to call `getInstance()`. I am well aware that the `assert()`'s only work in debug mode but this is fine for my project.

The class is intended to be used in the following way:

```
#include "Singleton.h"
#include <iostream>
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual ~Foo() = default;

protected: //has no public ctor's
    Foo(int i) //has no default ctor
        : i{ i }
    {
        std::cout << "foo ctr " << i << "\n"; //Not printed if no ctor of Foo is found
    }

private:
    int i;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Singleton<Foo>::initInstance(5); //Selects and executes Foo(int i).
    //Singleton<Foo>::initInstance(); //Should not compile, yet it does. Calls no ctor of Foo at all.
    Foo & theOnlyFoo = Singleton<Foo>::getInstance(); //or just use the return value of initInstance(5) to initialize this reference

    //...
    return 0;
}
```

**The problem:**

If I call `Singleton<Foo>::initInstance();` without any arguments, even though `Foo` has no default constructor, the code still compiles and runs. I would have expected that instantiating the constructor of `Singleton<Foo>` would fail because it calls `Foo`'s constructor with the arguments given but upon lookup it shouldn't be able to find an appropriate constructor. Yet the code compiles somehow.

When I execute the code the constructor of `Singleton<Foo>` is called but the constructor of `Foo` itself isn't. When I stop execution at a breakpoint just after `instance` has been initialized and inspect the value of its datamember `i` it is some random huge negative value indicating that simply no code was executed to initialize the instance of `Foo`.

This only happens when there is no appropriate constructor of `Foo` to call. When there is, everything works fine and `Foo`'s selected constructor is called.

Comment: Just a design question, but I don't see why you need `Singleton` to inherit from `T`.  Couldn't you use use `instance = new T(std::forward<Targs>(args)...);` instead?

Comment: No. A desirable property of the singleton classes themselves is that they don't expose any public constructors. This means that in `Singleton::initInstance()'` `T`'s ctor isn't accessible. Inheriting from `T` and then letting `Singleton`'s ctor call `T`'s ctor is my trick to get around this.

Comment: It fails to compile with gcc 7.3 and clang 5.0.0 if you try to use `Singleton<Foo>::initInstance();`. It looks like a VC compiler bug to me.

Comment: Are you using VS2017 update 5 or update 6 preview?

Comment: The aboutbox says version 15.5.5. So that's update 5 I guess?

Comment: There is another reason to have `Singleton<T>` inherit from `T`. This way `T`'s destructor can remain non-virtual since `Singleton` has no datamembers so, if done right, `T` doesn't necessarily have a vtable making it potentially a POD and trivially copyable (which you wouldn't with a singleton) and more of those wonderfull properties. The virtual dtor of `Singleton` is also not really necessary.

Comment: You could just [inherit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) `T`’s constructor(s).

Comment: @DavisHerring in `initInstance()`? I'm not sure if that works because... I get an internal compiler error..... man MSVC++ 17 is really buggy. This is just a hobby project and so far I've found 4 bugs.

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes, it does :p. Nice refinement by the way. I still need to call `Singleton`s ctor though but I won't have to implement it since calling it directly calls `T`'s ctor now (or actually I'm not sure what gets called when; `using` is still rather new to me). Also, with this change the problem in my question went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments this is probably a compiler bug. I submitted a bug report.

I also submitted a bug report for the internal compiler error that I encountered as I described in the comments. The internal compiler error happens when I (incorrectly) put `using T::T;` in `Singleton<T>::InitInstance()` and then call `T`s constructor.